# Add objects to a List nested inside a Dictionary using LINQ extensions

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary, foreach

I have `Dictionary<T, T>` that contains a key (that represents a category) with an empty `List<T>` as value:

```
Dictionary<string, List<IMyObject>> myObjects;
```

Each pair looks something like this:

```
{ firstCategory, new List<IMyObject>> }
```

I now have a `List<T>` of `IMyObject`'s:

```
List<IMyObject> myObjectsUnsorted;
```

I want to loop through `myObjectsUnsorted` and add to the correct `List<T>`

```
foreach (var myObject in myObjectsUnsorted)
{
    myObjects[myObject.Category].Add(myObject);
}
```

How can I do this without a loop? For example with a LINQ extension method? My other objects in this example is created with `.Select()` but that dosen't really fit the bill in this last `foreach`.

Comment: So you essentially want to do a for/each(WHERE) on a list with one expression?

Comment: Does the `Dictionary<K, V>` already exist and you only want to append? If so, I see no reason not to use `foreach`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would suggest using a [lookup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534291) instead:

```
ILookup<string, IMyObject> lookup = myObjectsUnsorted.ToLookup(t => t.Category);
```

`ILookup<,>` is precisely designed to be a "multiple values per key" dictionary. As well as being incredibly simple to construct, it has the benefit that if you look up a key which isn't represented, you get an empty sequence back instead of an exception. So you can *always* just write:

```
foreach (var item in lookup[key])
{
    ...
}
```

As opposed to:

```
IList<MyObject> list;
if (dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out list))
{
    foreach (var item in list)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Note that a lookup is immutable in that you can't change which items are in it after construction. (If the items are mutable reference types, you can modify the objects themselves of course...) That can be a blessing or a curse, depending on your situation...

Comment: It's worth mentioning though that this creates an immutable data structure, so no further additions/removals are possible like in dictionary solution.

Comment: 20 lines turned into 1, thanks a lot! Now I finally understands ILookup as well as a bonus! Immutable is definitely good to know, luckily it's a blessing this time. I use the pair in the view so I just do a `foreach (var item in lookup) { ... }` just as I did with the Dictionary. I'm using the key as a heading you see.

Comment: Jon, the last sentence about blessing or curse is just... amazing!

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `GroupBy` like so:

```
var dict = myObjectsUnsorted.GroupBy(q => q.Category)
                            .ToDictionary(q => q.Key, w => new List<IMyObject>(w));
```

Comment: @Jon Skeet's answer worked like a charm but this is definitely good to know in the future! Thanks!

Comment: I just realised that the only difference seems to be that `.ToLookup()` returns an `ILookup<IGrouping<T, T>>` and `.GroupBy()` returns an `IEnumerable<IGrouping<T, T>>`. Did I get that right?

Comment: @Oskar there is also `ToDictionary` after `GroupBy`, which changes `IEnumerable<IGrouping<T, T>>` to `Dictionary<T, T>`

Comment: Yeah I noticed that so at first I thought that was a must to get something useful but then I realized that `.GroupBy()` works just fine on it's own, just like `.ToLookup()` :)